# Prestashop - Create Carts and/or Orders through webservices from JS code

Tags: angular, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to integrade external Angular or SailsJS app with a Prestashop instance.

My target is creating Carts and Orders from it. I've been researching on google and experimental calls with postman. The fact is that I can GET all entities but when I try to POST a new register there is no way even I got all permissions...

Did someone reached making POST from JS code and JSON format for the new entity??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use prestashop api. 
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/

Also you can search in google "angular2-presta"

Comment: I'm using webservices and my trouble was generated by Apache, it was turning all requests into GET. Actually I got all request methods working. Thank you!